# Volume of a "tent"

Tags: integration, volume

In $(x,y,z)$-space, the ground is the $(x,y)$-plane $z=0$. Above the ground is constructed a giant tent whose height over $(x,y)$ is 
$$
h(x,y)=z=\frac{100}{1+(x^2+4y^2)^2}
$$
Find the volume enclosed by the tent (and the ground).

---

To me, the $x^2+4y^2$ suggests a change of coordinate. However, I don't know how to approach problems like this. This is a previous exam question so things like Wolfram Alpha should be not used. Could anyone outline a chain of thoughts as how to proceed with this type of problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+4y^2$ suggests indeed a change of coordinates. In particular, a shape:
$$
z= \frac{100}{1+(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$

would be circularly symmetric (so, in that case, what coordinates would you use?).

But in your exercise, instead of $y^2$, you have $4y^2$, that is, the $y$ are *dilated* of 1/2...so what is the ratio of the volumes of my shape and yours?

Answer (score 0):

You can let $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = 0.5r\sin\theta$. Next, realize that the surfaces bound will be your function $z=0$ and $z=f(x,y)$. The range of the bounds of the region $E$ will be from $0$ to $2\pi$ in $\theta$ and $0$ to $\infty$ in $r$ (think of it as a circle of "infinite radius"). Next, compute the Jacobian of the transformation and evaluate the iterated integral.